# Single EM imputation with R (using Amelia or other packages)

Tags: r, missing-data, expectation-maximization

I am trying to impute missing values with `R`. I would like to use the EM algorithm for that.

As it seems this algorithm is implemented in the `Amelia` package. However, `Amelia` is designed for multiple imputations (which I cannot use because of several reasons). Because of this `Amelia` imputes based on bootstrapped data and not the full original data set.

Is there a way to impute with EM using the full original dataset? Is this possible with `Amelia` or any other package?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A quick update on this question. We've updated Amelia to run without a bootstrap using the "boot.type" argument and setting it to "none":

```
library(Amelia)
data(africa)
a.out <- amelia(africa, ts = "year", cs = "country", m = 1, boot.type = "none")
```

This will run the EM algorithm on the original data once and works as of version 1.7.3.

Answer (score 1):

Amelia is not able to do EM imputation without bootstrapping out of the box at the moment (this information is based on a personal conversation with the package maintainer). However, I came up with a short and somehow dirty hack that helps you to do EM imputation in R (similar to the functionality in SPSS).

1. Download the current stable Amelia version from http://r.iq.harvard.edu/src/contrib/
2. Decompress the *.tar.gz on your computer
3. Open the file `emb.R` in the folder `R/`
4. Find the following function:

   `bootx<-function(x,priors=NULL){....`
5. There, replace the following lines:

   `order<-trunc(runif(nrow(x), min=1, max=nrow(x)+1))`

   `xboot<-x[order,]`

with

```
## Changed part, instead of bootstrapping just use the
## whole data set
#order<-trunc(runif(nrow(x), min=1, max=nrow(x)+1))
#xboot<-x[order,]
cat("CAUTION: THIS VERSION OF AMELIA DOES NOT BOOTSTRAP!")
xboot<-x
```

6. Save the source file
7. Compress the whole folder
8. Install the packages from your just changed source (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474081/how-do-i-install-an-r-package-from-source)).

I tested it with Amelia v1.6.4 and it works fine. Amelia now just uses the whole dataset for EM imputation.